# LEFT JOIN not returning NULL rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

A question with this title exists a number of times but I am having a hard time figuring it out in regards to my table.

I have a table with courses

```
id     |    name
1      |    course A
2      |    course B
```

and a table with videos for the courses

```
course_id    |     name
1            |     video A
1            |     video B
```

I want to retrieve all courses including how many videos they have. My query only returns course A but not course B (where there are no videos). But I still want course B to be returned

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(v.course_id) as num_videos FROM courses as c 
LEFT JOIN videos as v ON v.course_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `group by` here

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(v.course_id) as num_videos 
FROM courses as c 
LEFT JOIN videos as v ON v.course_id = c.id
GROUP BY v.course_id;
```